# Jquery Ajax Simple form annot get form to stop submitting with <Enter>

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

This is driving me nuts. 
No matter what I do I cannot keep this Ajax JQuery form from submitting whenever you hit enter in any of the form fields.

I keep looking into forums and none of the suggestions seem to help. I am refreshing my browser window, which I think will refresh all the code but this is getting crazy.

Please help!

```
<title>555</title>
<!-- jQuery --> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The Ajax Submit Script -->
    <script>
      $(function () {


        $('#msform').submit(function(e){

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'assets/upload.php',
            data: $('#msform').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
            return false;  
        });

      });   
    </script>


</head>
<body>


<!-- start error message div -->
<div id="form-messages"></div>
<!-- end error message div -->

<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" name="msform">
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Submit This</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">heidiho neighbor!</h3>
        <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Website" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: That code successfully stops the form from submitting when I test it — http://jsbin.com/guhuxi/1/edit?html,output — although, obviously, the alert saying it has been submitted after the Ajax response comes back will fires.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to capture Enter key on textboxes and disable them if found.

```
$(":text").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which==13)
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i really want to figure out the preventdefault actor. This may work but ti will reduce functionality universally.

Comment: `preventDefault()` will stop default behaviour of an element, if any. Suppose you have `form` and you want to stop `submit`, then if you use it, form will not be submitted. If you use it with hyperlink click, link will not browse to another location. So for textboxes, this is good idea as per my knowledge